# How to see command history log from SSH

Tags: shell, ssh, command-history

For some reason I can't see the command history log if someone ssh's into my account and runs some commands from my user account. If I run the history command in the terminal I only see my own commands that I have run. But not those of the person who ssh'ed into my account.

Is there a way to see what the person who ssh into my account is doing? What commands he is running from my account?

Comment: What makes you suspect someone logged into your account? Entries in `wtmp`? Files left over? Are you sure it's not e.g. a `cron` job?

Comment: If you are authenticating over ssh with public keys, you might try configuring the public key to execute a new bash session with a key specific history file... need to enable PermitUserEnvironment in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server and put `environment="HISTFILE=~/.hist2"` before the public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to see what the person who ssh into my account is doing? What commands he is running from my account?

You can use `sysdig` to monitor the ssh session activity:

```
sudo sysdig -A -c echo_fds proc.name=sshd
```

The `sysdig` can write the event to a dump file e,g:

```
sudo sysdig -C 1 -w dump.scap
```

it can be reviewed and filtred to check the user activity:

```
sudo sysdig -r dump.scap0 -c spy_users
```

[Sysdig Examples](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-Examples)